# How to find Wifi routers in network

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, kibana, wireshark, discovery

Good day

Do you have any idea how to find WIFI routers or devices which is connected to specific LAN sockets in network?

I am try find this devices from logs Elasticsearch + Kibana namely
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/configuration-interfaces.html
With this solution I have problem with set up : packetsbeats.

Other solution which I found is : WireShark or Advanced IP Scanner or Angry IP.
With this solution /tools is problem with default setting of routers / devices which is lock ports. Its mean I can get all IPs or MACs in network but how I will get know which is IPs or MACs belonging to Routers / NTB / Mobiles ect..?

From this reason I decide find routers in network from logs by Kibana.

Do have any idea or did you make something like me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11) is a layer-1/2 protocol, but routing is a layer-3 function, so there really is no such thing as a Wi-Fi router. There are some routers that have Wi-Fi interfaces, but they are routing a layer-3 protocol, e.g. IPv4, not Wi-Fi. Ports are layer-4 addresses for *some* layer-4 protocols, e.g. UDP, and they have nothing to do with routing layer-3 packets.

A router is simply a host on a layer-2 LAN. The configured gateway for your host is usually a router. The gateway is the host on a LAN to which your host sends packets destined to a different network.

Determining which hosts on a LAN are routers is a problem because you have no way to know which hosts are actually routers. You can have multiple routers on a LAN, but your host will be configured with one as its default gateway.

If you want to determine which host is the gateway for your host, then you should look at the configuration of your host, not at any particular host on the LAN.